# NSXMLParser question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsxmlparser

If I am trying to parse multiple xml using NSXMLParser and I try to parse xmls, when my delegate method such as didstartelement, didendelement and foundcharacters is called, how do i know from which NSXMLParser this method is being called for?

Comment: you might want to go thru this to get ur concept clear..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982030/how-can-i-send-multiple-url-request-from-a-nsurlconnection-delegate

Answer (score 4):

The first parameter to each of those delegate methods is the parser. That is the instance of NSXMLParser calling that method.