# How can I send multiple url request from a NSURLConnection delegate?

Tags: ios, xmlhttprequest, xml-parsing, nsurlconnection

This is the logical flow for my application:

1. At first, when the view controller has finished loading, then a `NSURLConnection` request can start its execution
2. The response consists in xml data
3. After parsing that xml I need to send another `NSURLConnection` request.
4. After sending the second request, if the response is ok, I receive other xml data
5. After parsing the second xml, I have to check some issues between first and second xml data.

So, is it possible to send multiple request? How? I do not need code, you could just explain it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sending multiple request from one class or multiple class??

Comment: i am sending multiple request from one class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viedDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self firstRequestMethod];

}

- (void)firstRequestMethod{

    NSString *myFirstRequestURL = @"<URL>";
    NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myFirstRequestURL];        

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if(returnData)
    {
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        //Parse your response here.
        //Is desired response obtain call the second Request, as described above
        if (TRUE) {  //on success
            [self secondRequestMethod];
        }

    }



}

- (void)secondRequestMethod{

    NSString *mySecondRequestURL = @"<URL>";
    NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:mySecondRequestURL];        

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if(returnData)
    {
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        //Parse your response here.
        //Is desired response obtain call the second Request, as described above
        if (TRUE) {  //on success
            //subsequent calls to other url, same as above
        }

    }



}
```

Hope this will help you understand better....

Comment: can tell me the full process plz? i have got your answer but i do not know how can i continue hole process.step by step just write the process plz, i did not use such kind of work before.

Comment: You can use a NSDictionary to be maintained between the two methods so that you can pass the values which you wish to check and compare in the secondRequestMethod and also subsequent url methods to come.. That won't be much of the issue for you...

Comment: It's a bad idea to use synchronous requests in the first place, it's pretty well explained [here](http://cocoaintheshell.com/2011/04/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/)

Comment: @Nikhita, synchronous requests have their pros and cons, We must use them as required. And using a Async req in above situation is not worth. And the post was to explain user about Synch call.

Comment: This isn't really a good answer. Synchronous requests can lock up the UI making the app unpleasant for the user. Its  better to use asynchronous threads so the user doesn't percieve the app as having "frozen" on them. (Plus it doesnt actually answer the question).

Comment: @Shayne, Yes, it does freeze UI, but as a developer, since our UI depends on the XML data of first and second request, we should display an UIActivityIndicatorView.

Comment: If the main UI is locked, that UIActivityIndicatorView won't even display, or at least that was the case when I last tried it, some years ago.

Answer (score 14):

I do this with the NSURLConnection Making them properties, then checking which one it is:

```
 @property (nonatomic,retain) NSURLConnection *myConnection;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSURLConnection *mySecondConnection;
```

then in the delegate:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

     if (connection == myConnection){
       //do something
    }

    if (connection == mySecondConnection){
       // do something else
        }

}
```

You can pass your NSURLRequest to the connection:

```
self.myConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer instead of sending synchronous request suggested in accepted answer.

Comment: I agree. This is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third party library available which is a wrapper on CFNetwork is [ASIHTTPREQUEST](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

This Library should do work for you. so that you don't have to write the code from scratch. other alternative is create one class which will be responsible for creating `NSURLConnection` then sending the request and finally notify to view controller using delegate or notification one data is received .

Comment: The class is not compliant with ARC. Better use NSURLConnection.

Comment: This WAS a good solution, but I believe the author has abandoned it. So I'll give it a +1 but this should be noted that whilst it WAS relevant, it isn't anymore.

Comment: Not using this library anymore but it was trully a great library - wish someone could maintain it. Some HTTPS server couldn't be connected using this library.